# Does argo rollout support header based traffic control in AWS App Mesh

Tags: envoyproxy, argocd, aws-app-mesh, argo-rollouts

Our service deployed on AWS EKS with AppMesh, ArgoCD is our CD tool, we need header based traffic management, we know Argo Rollout support traffic management with istio..., not sure AppMesh.

Is possible Argo Rollout support header based traffic control in AWS App Mesh

Thanks

https://argo-rollouts.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features/traffic-management/